# Cannot install php-ldap on CentOS 5 server

Tags: centos, php

I tried to install the `php-ldap` package on my machine but was not able to do so.

It shows missing dependencies error for `php-common`, but the said package is already installed and updated.

See the following screenshot:

[image: Package-manager error report]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
yum clean all
yum update
yum install php-ldap
```

...in that order.  If the `yum update` includes kernel or glibc updates, you should reboot after that step.

Comment: this is a running server that caters other services.

Would running clean all affects other installed packages?

Answer (score 0):

I have just resolved it by updating my PHP version from 5.4.37 to 5.6.
That did the charm and was able to install php-ldap.